# Need help with GRE question

Tags: arithmetic, contest-math

I encountered a question while preparing for GRE and am stuck.

> In an examination paper of 5 Questions, 5 percent of the candidates answered all of them and 5 percent none. Of the rest, 25% answered only one question, 20% only 4. If 24.5% of the entire candidates answered only two questions and 200 answered only 3 questions, how many candidates appeared in examination?

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Hint: What percent of the entire candidate group answered 3 questions? You should be able to figure that out easily.

Comment: I can see two different answers here. *The OP must be more confused than she was before!* `:D`

Comment: @pushpen.paul fixed :P

Comment: In my country, such question would be too easy to ask even for an entrance examination for junior high school.

Comment: @sawa Which country do you belong? Can you be specific?

Comment: Some East Asian country (It wouldn't make difference which one it is; They should all have the same reaction to a question like this).

Comment: so,why not u send me a booklet of such questions assuming me a junior school candidate :-P @sawa

Comment: or answer me @sawa:"The chairs in the school hall can be set out in 35 equal rows or in 45 equal rows or in 105 equal rows are:?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are being nasty, trying to fool you.

"Of the rest" means of the $90\%$ that remain after the two $5\%$ chunks are removed.  So the percentage who got $1$ is  $25\%$ of the $90\%$, which is $22.5\%$. Similarly,  the percentage that got $4$ is $18$.

But (trying to fool you again, assuming you did not get misled already) the $24.5\%$ refers to the whole group.

Thus all the questions except $3$ account for $5+5+22.5+18+24.5$ percent of the students. This sum is $75\%$.

That leaves $25\%$ who got $3$. But there are $200$ of these, so the total is $800$.

Comment: Excellent @Andre Nicolas